# How to combine dictionary + list to form one sorted list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Okay I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
z = {'J': 50, 'Q': 30, 'F': 10)
```

And a list that looks like this

```
l = [('J', 20), ('Q', 10), ('F', 2)]
```

How do I combine these into either a dictionary OR a list while keeping my original list sorted? I want something that looks like

```
l = [('J', 20, 50), ('Q', 10, 30), ('F', 2, 10)]
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
z = {'J': 50, 'Q': 30, 'F': 10}
l = [('J', 20), ('Q', 10), ('F', 2)]
print [(a, b, z[a]) for a, b in l]
```

gives:

```
[('J', 20, 50), ('Q', 10, 30), ('F', 2, 10)]
```

Best not to name your list `l`.  From [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Names to Avoid
>
> Never use the characters 'l' (lowercase letter el), 'O' (uppercase
>   letter oh), or 'I' (uppercase letter eye) as single character variable
>   names.
>
> In some fonts, these characters are indistinguishable from the numerals
>   one and zero.  When tempted to use 'l', use 'L' instead.

Answer (score 0):

For a list of tuples you can do:

```
[item + (z[item[0]],) for item in l]
```

Note that `z[item[0]]` assumes the key `item[0]` always exists in `z`.

For a dict, try

```
dict((item[0], (item[1], z[item[0]])) for item in l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving jena's answer to allow some items in the list missing from the dict:

```
>>> l = [('J', 20), ('Q', 10), ('F', 2), ('A', 5)]
>>> [x + (z.get(x[0]),) for x in l]
[('J', 20, 50), ('Q', 10, 30), ('F', 2, 10), ('A', 5, None)]
```